# What's the difference between Future.error and throw in dart Future?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

I'd like to understand when to use `throw` and `return Future.error` in async functions. Are there any underlying differences that we should take in consideration when choosing one or the other?

I did a small test:

```dart
Future testFuture() async {
  return Future.error('error from future');
}

void testThrow() {
  throw('error from throw');
}


Future testFutureThrow() async {
  throw('error from future throw');
}

main() async {
  print('will run test');

  try{
    await testFuture();
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e);
  }

  try{
    testThrow();
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e);
  }


  try{
    await testFutureThrow();
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e);
  }


  testFuture().catchError((e) => print(e));
  testFutureThrow().catchError((e) => print(e));

  print('did run test');
}
```

They both seem to work in the same way. This is the output:

```
will run test
error from future
error from throw
error from future throw
did run test
error from future
error from future throw
```

What we can see from this test is that, from the point of view of the caller, when call the function using `try/catch` the code runs synchronous and if we `Future.catchError` it's asynchronous. But from the point of view of the function flow it appears to be the same.

> NOTE: I had this initially as a response to a question. But then I realised that I was not answering but instead doing a question.

Comment: did you find an answer on this yet?

Comment: @brendan No I have not. Because I don't use dart on my normal job I kind of overlooked this since no one replied for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

**async** and **await** are a language extension/syntactic sugar to simplify working with asynchronous code by restoring a synchronous fashion.

Both abstract away working with **Futures** directly, making this code analogous:

```dart
  // On the callee's side
  Future<String> calleeAsync() async {
    return "from async callee";
  }

  Future<String> calleeSync() {
    return Future.value("from sync callee");
  }
```

```dart
  // On the caller's side
  Future<void> callerAsync() async {
    print("got ${await calleeAsync()}");
    print("got ${await calleeSync()}");
  }

  void callerSync() {
    calleeAsync()
        .then((v) => print("got3 $v"))
        .then((_) => calleeSync())
        .then((v) => print("got4 $v"));
  }
```

(while in callerSync the second `then()`'s callback could be merged with the first's, and the third `then()` could also be attached directly to `calleeSync()` because of monad-like associativity)

In the same manner, these functions are equivalent:

```dart
  // On the callee's side
  Future<void> calleeAsync() async {
    throw "error from async";
  }

  Future<void> calleeSync() {
    return Future.error("error from sync");
  }
```

```dart
  // On the caller's side
  Future<void> callerAsync() async {
    try {
      await calleeAsync();
    } catch (e) {
      print("caught $e");
    }
    try {
      await calleeSync();
    } catch (e) {
      print("caught $e");
    }
  }

  void callerSync() {
    calleeAsync()
        .catchError((e) => print("caught $e"))
        .then((_) => calleeSync())
        .catchError((e) => print("caught $e"));
  }
```

In summary, there is no practical difference. `return Future.error(…)` simply doesn't make use of the extensions an **async** function provides, thus it's more like mixing two flavours of asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that if you want to use `myFunc().then(processValue).catchError(handleError);` you should return Future.error but not throw it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fan101. My question was exactly because I started with that assumption. But when doing some simple test (the code in the initial question) it's not clear that what you presented is the only/correct way. Is that per guideline or is there any other considerations to have?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your initial question. If you were asking why   `testFuture().catchError((e) => print(e));
testFutureThrow().catchError((e) => print(e));`
ran asynchronously, because you had await statement in the `try catch` block but not for the `Future.catchError` statements.
As for the reason of my answer in the previous post, i encountered this problem when doing my flutter app project. `Future.catchError` simply won't  catch the error if you throw it. I am also curious why it worked in dart pad but not with flutter.